# retornar objeto json de função

Tags: android, json, funções, nullpointerexception

eu tenho uma função em android que faz a conexão com o servidor e me retorna um json, esse json e armazenado em uma variável chamada objeto.

porem tenho que fazer esse objeto ir para outra tela via return mas n estou conseguindo.

função

```
public class dados_ws {

    private static String URL;
    private static String TIPO;
    private static Map PARAMETROS;
    private static String CREDENCIAIS;

    public static JSONObject Dados_Ws(int pagina, String ParametroUrl , Context context) {

        switch (pagina) {
            //Recuperação de senha
            case 1:
                URL = Constantes_WebService.URL_REC_SENHA;
                TIPO = "GET";
                PARAMETROS = null;
                CREDENCIAIS = null + ":" + null;
                break;
        }

        WebService ws = new WebService(
                URL,
                ParametroUrl,
                TIPO,
                PARAMETROS,
                CREDENCIAIS,
                context
        );

        ws.getData(new WebService.RetornoAssincrono()

        {
            @Override
            public JSONObject onSuccess(JSONObject objeto) {
                System.out.println("Sucesso!!! Os valores são: \n" + objeto);

                return objeto;
            }
        });


        return null;
    }

}
```

retorno na outra pagina:

```
 JSONObject dadoslogin = null;
                        dadoslogin = Dados_Ws(1, ParametroUrl , context);
                        try {
                            int status = dadoslogin.getInt("status");
                            final String resultado = dadoslogin.getString("resultado");

                            System.out.println("Status = " + status);
                            System.out.println("Resultado = " + resultado);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            System.out.println("Catch : " + e.getMessage());
                            //hideDialog();
                        }
```

este código inserido direto na pagina inicial , retorna os dados perfeitamente, porem com a minha função da erro no app e diz que a variável esta nula.

Comment: pode colar o log do erro? Onde que dá null pointer, em dadoslogin, status ou resultado?

Answer (score 1):

Uma biblioteca muito boa para fazer parse é o Gson, é uma biblioteca da google, https://github.com/google/gson

exemplo para passar de json para objecto (objecto de nome Response):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Response response = gson.fromJson("string com o json", Response.class);
```

exemplo a passar de objecto (Objecto de nome "obj") para json:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(obj);
```